# PHPBB Post Export Contains Unexpected Results

Tags: forum, phpbb, sql

I am working on migrating a PHPBB forum for a client and have exported their posts table. I looked the SQL over and there's all kinds of random stuff—posts in Swedish (it's an English site), posts about random completely unrelated topics, etc.

I can't tell if these are spam posts and, if so, is there a way to find them and clean them up? I don't see any of these posts in the public facing forum. Any thoughts on what's going on?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any sort of automated or manual spam filtering set up? If manual, do you recall seeing these messages as email asking you to flag them as spam? In the db records, do they have any sort of flag that's different from the legitimate messages?

Comment: I suggest asking in the PHPBB forum, they will be the people who really know the subject.